# If we are selection Tag type as Login in Google tag manager ,then do we need to add trigger for that tag? How does the Login tag type work?

Tags: google-tag-manager, moengage

Not been able to track Login event in moengage

I am expecting to get the login event when user logs in to the system with the use of Tag type as Login. But unable to understand what else I am suppose to configure in order to track this event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the GTM tags needs a trigger. You need to trigger this `login` tag when the user is logging in.. It can not trigger automatically.
Create a Custom Event, lets say `login_event` and then add this trigger in the login tag.
Make sure you call this `login_event` from your web app at the time of login.